# Is there any difference in performance between these two instructions?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, criteria, performance

i have the following criteria specification and wanted to know if there is any difference in the performance or the memory usage of them.
1st way:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("case.estadoOperativo", Caso.EstadoOperativo.COMPLETADO))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("case.estadoAdministrativo", Caso.EstadoAdministrativo.TARIFICADO));
```

2nd way:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("case.estadoOperativo", Caso.EstadoOperativo.COMPLETADO));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("case.estadoAdministrativo",Caso.EstadoAdministrativo.TARIFICADO));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. After compilation, criteria.add and .add will become functionally identical. There's a possibility that one or the other will be slightly faster to compile, but the difference would be that of a few nanoseconds of compile time and no differences at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference, the `add` method returns `this` (for method chaining), not a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. From the api documentation at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/

```
add(Criterion criterion)
    Add a restriction to constrain the results to be retrieved.
```

You haven't actually retrieved any results yet. None of your restrictions will matter until you call .list()